# getOptionChain underlying & ticker columns

Tags: r, quantmod

The output of getOptionChain is a list. When applying over a list of tickers, I convert to a data.frame:

```
tickers = c("AAPL", "MSFT")

ls = llply(tickers, getOptionChain)

df = data.frame(matrix(unlist(ls), ncol = 7, byrow = FALSE))
```

However, I would like to have a column of the corresponding underlying price for each ticker and a second column with that particular ticker.

```
libs = c("quantmod","PortfolioAnalytics","plyr")
lapply(libs, require, character.only = TRUE)

startDate = as.Date("2014-01-01")
endDate = Sys.Date()

returns = do.call(merge, eapply(stkEnv, Ad))
dLn = na.omit(diff(log(stockReturns)))
names(dLn) = gsub("\\..+","",names(dLn))

last(dLn)

               AAPL      MSFT
2015-11-20 0.009287108 0.0043683
```

Comment: It's not clear what your desired output is.

Comment: Sorry, ideally a data.frame.

Comment: A data.frame with what columns? It would be helpful if you provided an example of the output you want, rather than a description.